# Problems to configure Rollup with Axios

Tags: axios, settings, rollup

I'm trying to setup axios in a Rollup's project but I can't make it works. I have uploaded an example to Github:

[Github repo](https://github.com/rickymuvel/rollup-axios-issue)

As you can see, I have made many configurations but it doesn't works. This is my rollup.config.js:

```js
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';
import builtins from 'rollup-plugin-node-builtins';
import globals from 'rollup-plugin-node-globals';
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
// import pkg from './package.json';

export default {
  input: 'src/index.js',
  output: {
    file: 'dist/bundle.js',
    format: 'umd',
  },
  external: ['axios'],
  plugins: [
    commonjs({
      browser: false,
      namedExports: {
        'axios': ['axios']
      }
    }),
    resolve({
      browser: true,
      preferBuiltins: false
    }),
    builtins(),
    globals(),
    babel({exclude: 'node_modules/**',  runtimeHelpers: true}),
    json()
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a bundle for browser, right?

The order of plugins is important, and for me this is perfectly working:

```js
[
  json(),
  replace({ options }),
  nodeResolve({ preferBuiltins: true, browser: true }),
  commonjs({ options }),
  babel({ options }),
]
```